# Can't select UICollectionViewCell in the xib file

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am doing a UICollectionView project but I didn't use storyboard to manage the views. I subclassed a UICollectionViewController in MyCollectionViewController with a MyCollectionViewController.xib file created. In the xib file, I dragged a Collection View onto the view, as the figure shown. [image]

I believe that the grey boxes are the Collection View Cells and I am supposed to click on them and change their Identifier so that these two lines of code recognize this is the cell.

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]  forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell"];
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell " forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

However, I couldn't click on the cells neither can I drag a new Collection View Cell onto the Collection View. I am getting the error message like this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier CollectionViewCell  - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The reason was I have used duplicated cell identifier: @"CollectionViewCell".

Change it and everything is working perfectly!

So, be aware of the identifiers! Make sure that each one is unique and don't even mess up with class names. Hopefully this can help out some people who have the same problem as me.